# Дисбаланс чтения/записи в коллекциях

Tags: java, массивы, netbeans

Netbeans часто выдает предупреждение "Дисбаланс чтения/записи в коллекциях".
Например, для этого кода во второй строке:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList();
  arr.add(1); arr.add(2); arr.add(3);
}
```

При этом описание ошибки отсутсвует и предлагается только отключить это оповещение.
Что значит это предупреждение и можно ли его игнорировать? Как его не допускать?

Comment: Как указал Pavel Mayorove, проблема возникает, если массив создан, в него добавляются элементы, но в дальнейшем он не используется. Т.е. дисбаланс - запись есть, чтения нет. После добавления последней строкой Integer s = arr.get(1); предупреждение исчезло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как [написано](https://netbeans.org/projects/www/lists/netcat/archive/2012-03/message/152) на сайте netbeans, такая ошибка возникает в случае записи данных в коллекцию, из которой потом никто не читает. Т.е. проблема либо в недописанном коде, либо в лишнем коде.

Comment: Судя по всему, вы правы. Добавил чтение из массива и предупреждение исчезло.